# Blank page when rendering Bootstrap Component in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am kind of new at Front-end development, and I encountered the following bug.
So, I was designing my own project - local store site, every component created by me, but eventually I came to the moment where I would like to use **Carousel** for displaying products etc, since I'm new and I just wanted to use clean Carousel designs I decided to use Boostrap for React (React-Boostrap). However, when I use it in my component, it renders my page completely blank, it even removes my Navbar component at the top.

I guess it is some Route issue which I could not identify by myself, so please kind developers, I need some help.

Here is the code: 
The Carousel component, **just copied and pasted it**, and wrapped it in Container (yes I tried to remove the container too that's not the issue),

```
import React from 'react'
import { MainContainer } from '../styles/Products.style'
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'

const Products = () => {
  return (
    <MainContainer>
      <Carousel>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img
        className="d-block w-100"
        src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940"
        alt="First slide"
      />
      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>First slide label</h3>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img
        className="d-block w-100"
        src="holder.js/800x400?text=Second slide&bg=282c34"
        alt="Second slide"
      />
  
      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img
        className="d-block w-100"
        src="holder.js/800x400?text=Third slide&bg=20232a"
        alt="Third slide"
      />
  
      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
  </Carousel> 
  </MainContainer>
     
  )
}

export default Products
```

This is the App.js :

```
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Products from "./components/Products";



function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path="/products" element={<Products/>}/>
        <Route path="/contact" />
        <Route path="/about" />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Login/>} />
        <Route path="/logout" />
        
      </Routes>

    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Annd Im not sure if it helps but, pasting it just in case - **package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0" // added this manually, just to try it it didnt work
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Hello, No I dont get errors, It is just pure white blank page.

Comment: Everything looks okay to me. I think the problem is in the `MainContainer` component. Kindly add it to the question.

Comment: Its not from the MainContainer, since I removed it, I tried with blank tag - ```<></>```, with empty ```<div></div>```, and also without anything else.

Comment: What route are you using when it happens?

Comment: You can see in the React Dev Tools (Extension in the Develover Tools in the Borwser) what components are in the Layout, this could be helpull in order to find what is happening

Answer (score 0):

I have copy/pasted your code and when I go to "/products" I can see the slider. However I had to comment out MainContainer because I have no code for it. (But you have said MainContainer is not the issue anyway).

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-vaughan-6bjv3t

Comment: Yeah, I tried to remove it too, but the outcome was pretty much the same.

Comment: but you see my code is working? where is the difference?